# Using template language in CSS files correctly

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm attempting to serve a CSS file through my url.py file so I can use template tags in my CSS.

Here's my code.

Base.html:

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/wideTitle.css" />
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^site_media/css/wideTitle.css','lightbearers.views.viewWideTitle'),
```

views.py:

```
def viewWideTitle(request):
    contentListAbout = About.objects.filter(Q(startDate__lte=datetime.now())).order_by('-startDate')
    if len(contentListAbout) > 0:
        contentAbout = contentListAbout[0]
    else:
        contentAbout = None
    ...
    return render_to_response('wideTitle.css', {'contentAbout':contentAbout, ...},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PARENT, "templates"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PARENT, "media/css"),
)
```

wideTitle.css (in /media/css):

```
#wideTitle{
    clear:both;
    height:180px;
    padding-left:0px;
    background: url({{ contentAbout.headerImage.url }}) no-repeat top left;
}
```

I can access the CSS file by entering its URL in my browser, but the Base.html isn't reading it at all. I think I've got everything decent; I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052341/using-a-django-variable-in-a-css-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550492/django-template-tags-in-javascript-and-css-files) for tips. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: which version of django are you using? don't you need to collect all static file in a separate folder for access in django? have you tried including the css style in templates instead of calling it through link tags?

Comment: Really well-written question, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Priyeshj: the CSS file here isn’t a static file, it’s a Django template.

Comment: It's not a great idea to serve static media through Django - you should leave that up to your web server. Instead why not have a template block in your base template that allows you to insert custom CSS in your templates that can be compressed at the top level

Comment: "normally" you shouldnt serve files through django. but I think its tempting to have template tags in the CSS file. But which goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @pastylegs: it’s not really static media though, is it? If the CSS is generated per request from a template then it’s not static.

Comment: ok, inline css is a bad thing but this looks worse! please use an img tag (somehow) or set style="background:url()" in the template file :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's tempting alright - and it is certainly useful at times but I'd be worried about having to conditionally configure the web server/proxy to allow certain paths within /media/ to be passed to the app-server to be generated and returned

Comment: @pastylegs having a view for this is enough masochistic, would you also share the same url as regular static files ? lol

Comment: @pastylegs: sure, I see your point. I just meant that the usual “don’t use Django to serve static files” applies to files that are served as-is, not all CSS files. Admittedly that doesn’t mean that serving a slightly variable CSS file from Django is a good idea either.

Comment: Open up Firebug or some other JS debugger, reload your page, check whether the page even tried to get your CSS by looking at the Net tab (in Firebug).

Comment: Minor issue: the call to `Q` appears to be redundant on the first line of `viewWideTitle`.

Comment: Maybe I'm going at this the wrong way. I'm dealing with a site someone else wrote and I have since made edits to. My client wants to be able to change the image in all the #wideTitle divs, and currently it's done using background-image. I've written a model to enable them to upload a file, but should I try to do this whole dynamic CSS shenanigan or use an img tag as @TommasoBarbugli suggests?

Comment: @Priyeshj: I'm using 3.1. I know some of my code is ancient history as far as Django syntax goes, but as I said, it's a pre-built site and I have yet to sharpen my Django skills enough to weed out all the old syntax.

Comment: @Spacedman: Oddly enough, Chrome's Inspector loads a blank css file, but as mentioned, if I type in the direct url for the file, I can see it all fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the generated stylesheet being served with the correct mime type? If not, the browser might not interpret it as CSS.

I can’t remember if `render_to_response` accepts `content_type='text/css` as an argument, but there is a way to set it if Django isn’t already using the correct mime type.

**Edit:** as [@TommasoBarbugli pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285408/django-using-template-language-in-css-files-correctly/9285565#comment11708999_9285565), you want the `mimetype` argument for `render_to_response`.

(Firefox’s Firebug add-on, or the Web Inspector in Chrome/Safari, should be able to show you the stylesheet’s mime type.)

Comment: Ah, `mimetype` rather than `content_type` — that does make more sense.

Comment: That did it! Thanks @PaulD.Waite. I'm still unsure whether this is the best way to do all this, but at least it works...

Comment: @reK1NDLE: excellent, glad we figured out why it wasn’t working. I’m not sure if this is the best way to achieve your desired functionality either — that might be worth a question of its own.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli I ended up pulling the data from the model in the templates using `background:url()`. Kinda violated DRY because I had to add it to so many templates, but I think it's better than serving the CSS through Django in the long run. Thanks!